# How to number and centralize the heading "reference"

Tags: bibtex, horizontal-alignment

In line with journal format, I want my "Reference" heading numbered as a section on its own. The number should follow that of "Acknowledgement"  which I have numbered as 8. Now it remains to number the reference section as "9. Reference" and centralized too.. But I use `bibtex` for my referencing. How do I achieve this numbering and centralizing of the heading "Reference"?

Alternatively, how do I disable the "Reference" heading so that the heading is blank. I can add the "9  Heading" manually using `\section{9.  Heading}`?

The centering I did for all other sections have been manually carried out and not with any package. I did the other centering with the following example:

```
\begin{center}{\large\textbf{{5.    Grid approach to the Jouannaud-Lescanne submultiset-based multiset ordering}}}\end{center}
```

Here is an MWE for perusal:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setcounter{page}{158}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\lfoot{\textrm{\textit{bla bla bla...}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textrm{\textit{bla bla bla...}}}
}
\markright{\textrm{\textit{bla bla bla...}}}
\tolerance 1000
\title{\LARGE{\textbf{bla bla bla...
}}}
\author{\large{bla bla bla $^{1}$ and bla bla bla $^{2}$}\\ \\ \small{$^{1}$bla bla bla...} \\ \small{(bla...).} \\ \small\textit{bla...} \\ \\ \small{$^{2}$(bla bla bla...)} \\ \small{bla bla bla...} \\ \small{\textit{bla...}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}{\large\textbf{{1.    Introduction}}}\end{center}
%...body of article
\renewcommand{\markboth}[2]{}
\bibliography{C:/Users/HP/Macpee_Document/bibliography_data/RefDatabase}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Could you please add a mwe including which class you are using. It would help a lot in finding a solution.

Comment: This question follows the ad-hoc discussion in [How to remove unwanted header ( “REFERENCE”)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285639/5764)...

Comment: We need more information, seriously. And by that I mean a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Here's why: sectional units are heavily influence by the `\documentclass` and most certainly by packages that you load. Headers as well. Moreover, it seems like you're writing an article for a journal submission, which may come with its own restrictions in terms of what can/not be used. As such, proposed solutions might be helpful, but may also not conform to the journal requirements. Please update your post with the relevant information requested in the linked post.

Comment: @Werner I kind of realised as much, but even in that discussion the details are rather sparse. The issue I have is whether all sections are already centred or only the Reference one should be. If the class/document already defines `\section{}` to be centred, then using the `tocbibind` package with the `numbib` option should be enough. But if writing for a journal there may be other options available to number the reference section (e.g., the class could be using something like `natbib` or something more bespoke).

Comment: I somehow think you would be more satisfied using plain TeX.

Comment: Out of interest, which journal are you going to submit to?

Comment: I think my question is clear enough with the MWE and my output file. Mentioning of names of journals is not necessary. Why the use of plain tex, does it mean Xetex cannot achieve what plain tex can achieve? Moreover, the manuscript contains serious mathematical symbols and fonts (the like of French script) in Math mode, and warrants the use of Xetex which I think plain tex cannot achieve.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is really going against all good practices of using LaTeX. The whole idea of LaTeX is to separate formatting from content, and you are formatting everything manually, which is why you are finding things so difficult.  What you should be doing is using appropriate packages to format your section headings and then things should work more or less automatically.  Here is a version of your document to get you started.

I've used the `authblk` package to format the author blocks, the `titling` package to format the title and the `titlesec` and `titleps` packages to format the section headings and page headers and footers.

The `natbib` package makes the references section an unnumbered section by default. To number it you simply need to redefine the `\bibsection` macro to be a regular section. Of course this only works if you are using proper sectioning commands in the first place.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% This part just makes the document self-contained and is not needed
% except for the example code
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titleps}
% The following code formats sections as centered and numbered.
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\filcenter\large\bfseries}%
  {\thesection.}{1em}{}
% And the same for subsection
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}%
  {\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
% This code creates the headers and footers using a pagestyle called 'main'
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead[\thepage][][] % even
          {}{}{\thepage}} % odd
\pagestyle{main}
\setcounter{page}{158}
% This package adds dummy text for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}
% This package allows finer control over the formatting of the title elements
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
% This package allows a simple formatting of the author blocks
\usepackage{authblk}
\author[1]{First Author}
\author[2]{Second Author}
\affil[1]{First Affiliation\authorcr Address\bigskip}
\affil[2]{Second Affiliation\authorcr Address}
\title{A title}
\date{}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
% Since natbib uses an unnumbered section by default we define \bibsection
% to make it a regular numbered section.
\renewcommand\bibsection{\section{\refname}}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\cite{Saussure1995}\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Acknowledgements}
Thanks.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Well thanks Alan. Actually, I did not attend  any  LaTex class, neither am I a programmer. I just manage to have my papers LaTex typet, and they have always appeared really nice, even though I have been mixing formatting with contents. I will try to put your answer to use. However, one thing is still missing in your answer - the reference number. I look forward to your anwer on that. Once again thanks for your effort.

Comment: As a matter of fact, both the Acknowledgement and the Reference headings are also numbered. I do not know why  the journal chose to make their template like that.

Comment: @macpee I updated my answer.  You don't need to be a programmer to use LaTeX nor have taken a class.  But you might want to get yourself a good book.  You will save yourself much time and frustration by doing things with packages rather than by hand.

Comment: Ohh that's nice. I'm grateful.